# flutter_bloc library increment decrement button using flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm pretty new to flutter_bloc library and i'm trying to make component of increment decrement button but when I tried to duplicate the component, i face the problem, when I push the second increment button component the first component updated too like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v7re.png). I want them to have separated result. how can i fix that?

here is my bloc code:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

abstract class QtyEvent{}

class Increment extends QtyEvent {}

class Decrement extends QtyEvent {}

class QtyBloc extends Bloc<QtyEvent, int> {
  QtyBloc() : super(0) {
    on<Increment>((event, emit) =>
      emit(state+1));
    on<Decrement>((event, emit) =>
      emit(state-1));
  }
}
```

and here is my component code:

```
class _QtyState extends State<Qty> {
  int _n = 0;
  @override
  void add() {
    setState(() {
      _n++;
    });
    context.read<QtyBloc>().add(Increment());
  }

  void minus() {
    setState(() {
      if (_n != 0) _n--;
    });
    context.read<QtyBloc>().add(Decrement());
  }

  QtyBloc qtybloc = QtyBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),), 
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: minus,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.red),
                  child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                context.watch<QtyBloc>().state.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: add,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.red),
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is doing exactly what it was designed to do.
If I understand correctly, you want to use the same Bloc to have two *sets* of `increment` & `decrement` buttons?

Since you are `emitting` a single `state`, when you update it in one place, it updates everywhere!

Also, you do not need to call `setState` as it re renders the UI which can be achieved by bloc it self.

And, in the heading you mentioned you use `flutter_bloc` but in your code, you are using `bloc`.

[Flutter Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

[Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)

Here is how to implement it with `flutter_bloc`,

`logic.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class CounterEvent {
  const CounterEvent();
}

class Increment extends CounterEvent {
  final int value1, value2;
  const Increment({this.value1 = 1, this.value2 = 1});
}

class Decrement extends CounterEvent {
  final int value1, value2;
  const Decrement({this.value1 = 1, this.value2 = 1});
}

class Reset extends CounterEvent {
  final int value;
  const Reset({this.value = 0});
}

class CounterState {
  final int s1, s2;                                       // Just maintain 2 values!
  const CounterState({required this.s1, required this.s2});
}

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc(CounterState initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    if (event is Increment) {
      yield CounterState(
          s1: state.s1 + event.value1, s2: state.s2 + event.value2);
    } else if (event is Decrement) {
      yield CounterState(
          s1: state.s1 - event.value1, s2: state.s2 - event.value2);
    } else if (event is Reset) {
      yield CounterState(s1: event.value, s2: event.value);
    }
  }
}
```

`component_page.dart`

```dart
class Component extends StatelessWidget {
  const Component({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Counter'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context)
                          .add(const Decrement(value1: 1, value2: 0));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    state.s1.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context)
                          .add(const Increment(value1: 1, value2: 0));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context)
                          .add(const Decrement(value1: 0, value2: 1));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    state.s2.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context)
                          .add(const Increment(value1: 0, value2: 1));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context)
                          .add(const Reset(value: 0));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.red),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Note

- This code is written with null safety
- Remember to add `BlocProvider` around your app, like so:

`main.dart`

```dart
void main() async {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(
      create: (_) => CounterBloc(const CounterState(s1: 0, s2: 0)),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Component(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @RakaPrasetyo accept the answer please

Comment: Can someone refactor this code for Flutter_bloc 8.0?